# Spring JPARepository querying many to many intersection table

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entity classes as follows (Example taken from https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-extra-columns-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/)

**Book class**

```
@Entity
public class Book{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<BookPublisher> bookPublishers;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        bookPublishers = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<BookPublisher>   getBookPublishers() {
        return bookPublishers;
    }

    public void setBookPublishers(Set<BookPublisher> bookPublishers) {
        this.bookPublishers = bookPublishers;
    }
}
```

**Publisher class**

```
@Entity
public class Publisher {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<BookPublisher> bookPublishers;

    public Publisher(){

    }

    public Publisher(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "publisher")
    public Set<BookPublisher> getBookPublishers() {
        return bookPublishers;
    }

    public void setBookPublishers(Set<BookPublisher> bookPublishers) {
        this.bookPublishers = bookPublishers;
    }
}
```

**Intersection Table**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_publisher")
public class BookPublisher implements Serializable{
    private Book book;
    private Publisher publisher;
    private Date publishedDate;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
    public Publisher getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(Publisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    @Column(name = "published_date")
    public Date getPublishedDate() {
        return publishedDate;
    }

    public void setPublishedDate(Date publishedDate) {
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }
}
```

I want to query 2 things,

1. Get list of books belonging to a particular publisher e.g. get all books associated with publisher 100
2. Get list of books not associated with a particular publisher e.g. get all books not associated with publisher 100

I want to achieve this using a simple JPARepository query if possible like findByXYZIn(...) etc.

Please let me know if querying a many to many relation is possible using JPA repository queries and if yes, whether I can do it directly or would it require any changes in the entity classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `BookRepository`

Get publisher's books

`findBooksByBookPublishersPublisherId(Long publisherId)`

Get books not published by publisher

`findBooksByBookPublishersPublisherIdNot(Long publisherId)`

IMHO `Publication` is much more apropriate name then `BookPublisher` in your case as `Publisher` by itself could be `BookPublisher` (a published that publishing books)

Comment: Excellent. This is what I was looking for. Just got confused with the naming convention of the JPA method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can make it just by method name. But you definitely can use JPA query. Something like this: `"SELECT b FROM Book b JOIN b.bookPublishers bp JOIN bp.publisher p WHERE p.id = ?1"`. and with not equal for the second case

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use named Queries to fulfill your requirements:

```
@Query("select b from Book b where b.publisher.idd = ?1")
Book findByPublisherId(int id);

@Query("select b from Book b where b.publisher.idd <> ?1")
Book findByDifferentPublisherId(int id);
```

Take a look at [**Using `@Query`** Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) for further details.